# не работает css в php совместно с бутстрап

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

попробовал в целях обучения сверстать сайт через bootstrap. Подключил два стиля, собственный и бутстрап. Подключал так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Z:\home\newsite\www\css\style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>PHP новый сайт</title>
```

В итоге не работают мои стили.

Comment: если стили bootstrap - работают, а ваши нет, то проблема в порядке подключения файлов (вы, скорее всего, называете классы также как и bootstrap).
подключите Ваши стили самыми последними и увидите изменения.

Comment: Просто поменять местами ? Я правильно понял ?

Comment: <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Z:\home\newsite\www\css\style.css">

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PHP новый сайт</title>
</head>